# Replace a column in postgres table with pandas column using sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a postgres table that I read into a pandas DataFrame. I then apply some functions that change all values in 1 column to other values. I need to find a way to then update the corresponding column in the postgres table. Is there a straightforward way of doing this? The basic workflow I need is like:

```
df = pd.read_sql(...)
df.col_to_update = apply_some_functions_to_col(df.col_to_update)
sa.update(tbl).values({"col_to_update": df.col_to_udpate})
```

Though this particular statement wouldn't work because the API here doesn't understand pandas series.

Comment: If you have the whole table in memory,  its probably easiest to just drop the old table and create a new one